# Task of the guy who reads the score and sits next sound technician at movie

Tags: classical-music, live-sound, live

Yesterday I was at a Lord of the Rings Live concert and I was wondering, what these two guys were doing. They were sitting next to the sound technician and reading the score and they were wearing headphones and had some kind of controller in their hands. Although they had a monitor like the conductor. Are they checking the speed? Or if everyone is right, or do they regulate the mix, especially of the solists? I don't know so I'm aksing you!

*"A little hope ist left"*, Galadriel

Comment: I guess they can read the score and tell their colleague when a certain point in the music is reached when some audio/video/... setting has to be changed. It might be too difficult for one person to read a score and control other things at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF he's reading the score, probably the Sound Assistant or A2.  In theater you usually have a tech "on book" with the score to coordinate upcoming cues, sync with the conductor and most importantly let the Sound Engineer know when there are specific sound cues to mark. If there are sound effects that the orchestra isn't providing then they are cued from the console.

The controller he was using could be for the monitors, working the back of house sound which is what the A2 usually does. He also could be on the effects cues while the other engineer mixed the Front of House sound.

Edit* read the question again, realized it was two people AND a sound engineer. They could still be doing the Sound Assistant job together.

Comment: This sounds logical :D

Answer (score 1):

Stage lighting would be my guess.

Comment: The lighting tech has their own console, and is usually controlled from a booth.

Comment: Stage light ist in a Room above as far as I know.